# Is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function:

$$f(x,y) := \frac{x^2|y|^{\frac{3}{2}}}{x^4 + y^2} \quad \text{if} \quad (x,y)\not=(0,0)$$

and $f(0,0) := 0$. Is this function continuous at $(0,0)$? Its graph tells me that is continuous so I tried an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument but I'm not able to get the right inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it is not necessary to go down to the $\epsilon - \delta$ argument.

At $(0,0)$, $\frac{1}{2} \lvert y \rvert^{\frac{1}{2}} \to 0$ so $x^2 \lvert y \rvert^{\frac{3}{2}} = o(2 x^2 \lvert y \rvert)$. Also, by developing $(x^2 - \lvert y \rvert)^2 \geq 0$ you get $2 x^2 \lvert y \rvert \leq x^4 + y^2$. Therefore $x^2 \lvert y \rvert^{\frac{3}{2}} = o(x^4 + y^2)$.